# setText in listView keeps changing when you scroll down because of recycle

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-recyclerview

I know that in android, a listview recycles its elements and in my case, the listview recycles them when you scroll down.

I'm trying to make a feed that lets me "Like" a post.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final HomeFeedHolder homeFeedHolder;

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_feed_item, null);
        homeFeedHolder = new HomeFeedHolder();
        homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHomeFeedLike);
        convertView.setTag(homeFeedHolder);
    } else {
        homeFeedHolder = (HomeFeedHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.getText().toString().equals("Like")) {
                HomeFeedModel homeFeedModel = (HomeFeedModel) getItem(position);
                int pid2 = item.getId();
                String pid = Integer.toString(pid2);
                HomeFeedLikePost homeFeedLikePost = new HomeFeedLikePost(position);
                homeFeedLikePost.execute(pid);
                homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setText("Unlike");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, I call setText("Unlike") after the tvHomeFeedLike is pressed. It works perfectly but when I scroll down and the listview is recycled, the "Like" changes to another post. How can i make it so that it is by individual post?

**EDIT: I am also using Volley**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the set of liked items id to the adapter:

```
Set<Integer> likedItems = new HashSet<>();
```

In getView:

```
    int pid = (HomeFeedModel) getItem(position);
    if (likedItems.contains(pid))
        homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setText("Unlike");
    else
        homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setText("Like");
```

In onClick:

```
    if (likedItems.contains(pid)){
        likedItems.remove(pid);
    }
    else{
        likedItems.add(pid);
    }
    if (likedItems.contains(pid))
        homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setText("Unlike");
    else
        homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setText("Like");
```

Answer (score 0):

add a boolean field to your item class.

```
if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_feed_item, null);
        homeFeedHolder = new HomeFeedHolder();
        homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHomeFeedLike);

        convertView.setTag(homeFeedHolder);
    } else {
        homeFeedHolder = (HomeFeedHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(item.isLike()) homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setText("Unlike");
    else homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setText("Like");

    homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



    if(homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.getText().toString().equals("Like")) {
                    HomeFeedModel homeFeedModel= (HomeFeedModel) getItem(position);

                        int pid2 = item.getId();
                        String pid = Integer.toString(pid2);
                        HomeFeedLikePost homeFeedLikePost = new HomeFeedLikePost(position);
                        homeFeedLikePost.execute(pid);
                        homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setText("Unlike");
                        item.setLike(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: like is a boolean so the getter should be isLike() instead of getLike()

Comment: Let me gess in your xml file the text tvHomeFeedLike is set to like.

Comment: Once you change an item of the listview. the item will be recycled with the new state.

Comment: yes, i need a solution. i am looking for a solution to somehow get the old item and continue to have the text set

Comment: You have to store the state of the tvHomeFeedLike textview of every item.
You have to restore the state of every  tvHomeFeedLike textview in the getView method.

Comment: how can i do that? Also, I edited the op. I am using volley

Comment: Add a boolean field to your HomeFeedModel

Comment: would you please update the code of the adapter to see you did exactly

Comment: look at JpCrow's answer, i did everything he told me to do

Comment: set in the HomeFeedModel the like field to true by default

Comment: in the HomeFeedModel class 
 private boolean like = true;

Answer (score 0):

in your HomeFeedModel object you should add a param that it would be something like this:

```
 public class HomeFeedModel {

    //all your attrs

    private boolean isLiked;

    public boolean isLiked(){
        return isLiked;
    }

    public void setIsLiked(boolean liked){
        isLiked = liked;

    }
  }
```

Then you should assign the params outside the onClick function because it will take the current position while you are scrolling, not the one you are looking for (this because of recycling). 
Also change the object state to liked or not and assign to the textview the state in order to always have the latest state of the object and not the recycled one.

You should try like this:

```
    final boolean isLiked = homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.getText().toString().equals("Like");
    final HomeFeedModel homeFeedModel= (HomeFeedModel) getItem(position);
    final int pid2 = item.getId();
    final String pid = Integer.toString(pid2);
    final HomeFeedLikePost homeFeedLikePost = new HomeFeedLikePost(position);

    homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setText(homeFeedModel.isLiked() ? "UnLike" : "Like"); 
   homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(isLiked) {
                homeFeedLikePost.execute(pid);
                homeFeedModel.setIsLiked(false);
                homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setText("Unlike");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: nope, doesn't work. I clicked "Like" on the first post and it changed to "Unlike" and then scrolled down and then scrolled back up and the "Unlike" changed back to "Like"

Comment: Did you add in your HomeFeedModel the  isLiked  boolean? This code is working for me... Are you sure you have the same one?

Comment: Please add your HomeFeedModel and your homeFeedLikePost class. Also you have this line right?  homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setText(homeFeedModel.isLiked() ? "UnLike" : "Like");

Comment: Yes i have that line but how do i notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: Yes i added that but now when i click "Like", it does not  turn to "Unlike"

Answer (score 0):

When you press like and `setText("Unlike")` for a particular item, you have to keep that state.

First you have to understand how `getView()` works. Your `getView` method basically helps you to load the item when you scroll to its position. What view to display is up to you. In particular, you can define what UI elements should show (text, image, button etc.). Some UI elements are status-dependent.

In your case, `TextView` shows "Unlike" when a post is liked and vice versa. That `TextView` is status-dependent. Therefore, you have to "remember" your post status somewhere.. By saving the status, next time when you scroll to that item, your `getView` method can decide what text to show:

```
HomeFeedModel homeFeedModel= (HomeFeedModel) getItem(position);
int pid2 = item.getId();
HomeFeedLikePost homeFeedLikePost = new HomeFeedLikePost(position);
boolean isLiked = homeFeedLikePost.isLiked();
if (isLiked) {
     homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setText("Unlike");   
} else {
     homeFeedHolder.tvHomeFeedLike.setText("Like");
}
```

In above example, `isLiked` is one of the property in your `HomeFeedLikePost`. That means, the moment you `Like` a post, you should update this property in your DB as well (do it inside your `onClickListener`).

Hope that makes sense to you.

Comment: Yes very well explained. The .execute (asynctask) is the code to check if the post returned like is found or not found in the database. It will return "success" if it is found. How do I implement that to work?

Comment: I think that depends on your design. So you are using an async task to find if a post has been liked or not.. My idea is, each post should be an entry in your db. and each post should have fields like id, title, content, *liked* etc. When you load post data into ListView, you get your post data, and post.liked will tell you if a post has been loaded or not. That means, what your asyncTask should do is to mark post "liked" true or false when you click.

Comment: I already have that implemented. i can return 1 or 0 if it's existing or not existing.

Comment: then call that in your `getView`

Comment: your current code does not call `setText` in `getView` but only call inside onClickListener. you can either add it above setOnClickListener or update your question so I can see what goes wrong after your updated code.